# how does django sort the models in django admin in chinese?

Tags: django, django-admin

Django version: 1.10.7

I have an django app built for chinese end users.

In django admin, the models are ordered by alphabetically for English. When I switch to Chinese, the models are re-ordered.

I want to know how they are ordered and determined by which part of the Django software.

I know the line is : https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.7/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L458

I still don't understand how the sorting is done for Chinese

Comment: Line is here. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L471 Change the git tag to 1.10 (will be same)

Comment: Thanks. So how does it sort for Chinese? I still can't tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're storing `verbose_name_plural` in UTF-8, then the modal would be sorted in UTF-8 encoding. It depends on the string encoding.
Like:

```
>>> a=[u'甲-1', u'乙-2', u'丙-3']
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
[u'\u4e19-3', u'\u4e59-2', u'\u7532-1']
```